# Let $R \subseteq S \subseteq R[X]$. Does $R$ noetherian imply $S$ is also Noetherian?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian

Think title is fairly self explanatory.
Here Ring = Commutative + Unitary

Comment: Think I messed my LaTeK up :(((

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.